# Is it possible to get a bachelor's degree just by having more than the required credit hours?

Tags: advisor, united-states, university, degree

I have around 126 completed credit hours and I know the required amount is 120. My major is in education and I was originally planning on becoming a teacher however I am no longer sure if that is the route I want to pursue and I have not entered the teaching program at my university. I have not been back in the classroom for at least a year mainly because I don't want to waste money and time continuing something that I'm not sure I want to do for a good chunk of my life. I know not every university is the same but is it possible to acquire a Bachelor's just by having more than the required credit amount or will I have to change my degree plan around?

PS. i have emailed the last advisor i spoke with but it's been awhile and i havent recieved a response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, a degree requires more than just a certain number of credits. There are usually specific requirements for certain courses, and more requirements for credits and courses within a "major". A minimum GPA is a requirement and there may be a separate GPA-in-major requirement.

But, you may have actually accumulated all of the requirements for a degree in some field if you don't care what it is. There is also some shortest path to graduation for you in any case. Someone like the university's "registrar" knows all of these things and can give you advice. But your advisor should be able to help, or even a secretary in one of the departments in which you have a lot of courses.

So, yes, you may need to change your plans, but you need specific advice from the institution offering the degree.